# Any way to kill String.prototype.match after specified time passed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I'm writing a program like this.

```
const regexp = new RegExp(/* user input */);
if (message.text.match(regexp)) {
  /* do something */
}
```

I'm afraid of ReDoS so I want to terminate the `.match` calculation if it runs more than one second or something.

Is there any way to do this on Node.js?

Comment: No, but usually your frontend, like Nginx, should take care of timeouts. `.match` is not the only thing that can cause the program to hang.

Comment: have your node server spawn a new process, pass it the input, and kill it if it doesn't output after however long.